# Why is my deployed MATLAB application unable to generate a new figure?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-deployment, figure

I have built a GUI with some text boxes and a pushbutton. When I execute the GUI from MATLAB, it produces the desired plot on a separate window. The plot is created by a function that is stored in the same directory and is called in the callback function of pushbutton.

When I package it with the .m file of the GUI as the main file, I get an exe. When this exe runs, it normally takes data from data source (sqlserver) but then does not give the plot in a separate window as within matlab (also not in the same GUI window). There is a sound and from the behaviour it seems that the plots appears and vanishes in a very short time. But this is my perception and may be wrong, maybe it is some error message that is suppressed.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I am packaging as windows standalone application

Comment: Does it work if you make a trivial GUI which just plots this kind of figure in a separate window? And are you sure that the data import and everything preceding/following the plot goes well?

Answer (score 1):

You've run into the problem discussed here in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245275)

Once the code is finished evaluating it cleans up, including closing the window you created.  One solution would be to pause your script right after plotting.

[Here's a discussion of many functions that can be used to pause execution with a GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15K5T/).

Comment: That might be a possible option.....since a window opens suddenly and disappears in a matter of millisecs....I cant see it properly...But pausing the code....can you tell me how?    About the process..I had a gui.fig and gui.m file. now the pushbutton callback Pulls data from Mysql based on the values I put in the text boxes(this part is fine...i can see data being imported from my sql) then it calls a function which was previously in a separate m file in same folder, but now i copied the function in gui.m. the figure is created within that function.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. The `uiwait()` function in my edit is probably the easiest to start with.  Without knowing many more details about your specific problem, I can't offer more.